# NIntegrate and Indefinite boundaries -- Why does it do this?

Tags: numerical-integration

Could someone help me understand why I'm seeing the following behavior?

I'm trying to evaluate the following function

```
NIntegrate[{Exp[- x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x ]] , {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Which I expect to converge to a value of 0.5 as sdM approaches 0.
For 'large' values of `sdM`, such as 0.35, Mathematica has no problem with the integration.  Specifically,

```
NIntegrate[{Exp[- x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x ]] , {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]/.{sdM -> 0.35}
```

returns,

```
0.563165
```

However, if I make sdM small, such as 0.001, I get a value of 0,

```
NIntegrate[{Exp[- x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x ]] , {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]/.{sdM -> 0.35}
```

returns,

```
0.
```

I'm not too surprised by this. As I understand, this results from the indefinite boundaries and the limited region of the density function that has a value greater than $MachineEpsilon.

However, if I split the integration into two parts to ensure that the function is evaluated at x = 0, I still get 0.  That is,

```
(NIntegrate[{Exp[- x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x ]] , {x, -\[Infinity], 0}]+ NIntegrate[{Exp[- x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x ]] , {x, 0, \[Infinity]}])/.{sdM -> 0.0001}
```

This is despite the fact that the density function is clearly non zero at x = 0.

Questions

1. Why does it behave like this?
2. Is there a better way to assign an evaluation point in NIntegrate besides splitting the evaluation at that point?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both [`MinRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinRecursion.html) and [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

int[sdM_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  {Exp[-x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} *
   PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], 
    Exp[x]], {x, -∞, ∞},
  MinRecursion -> 4,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

int /@ {0.35, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0005, 0.0001}

(* {{0.563164672134101, 0.500000000000000}, {0.500012500075248, 
  0.499999999997122}, {0.500000500000259, 
  0.500000000000134}, {0.500000125000008, 
  0.500000000000000}, {0.500000005000000, 0.500000000000000}} *)
```

Comment: I'm curious why WorkingPrecision fixes this issue.  I would have thought it important if we are dealing with universally very low values of the integrand.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Machine precision calculations tend to lose precision and accuracy for complicated calculations since there is no attempt to track or control precision. Numeric techniques exacerbate this since they are very numeric calculation intensive. Specifying a `WorkingPrecision` switches to arbitrary-precision calculations that track and attempt to control the precision. Increasing the `MinRecursion` forces a finer subdivision of the integration region.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello sir i think you have to work with** `WorkingPrecision`

```
i1 = NIntegrate[{Exp[-x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[
     LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x]], {x, -\[Infinity], 0}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10] /. {sdM -> 0.0001}

i2 = NIntegrate[{Exp[-x]/(Exp[-x] + 1), 1/(Exp[-x] + 1)} PDF[
     LogNormalDistribution[0, sdM], Exp[x]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10] /. {sdM -> 0.0001}


i1 + i2
```

[image]